# How to pass one MethodField data to another MethodFiels in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a SerializerMethod field like below

```
cal = models.SerializerMethodField('__getcal__')
def __getcal__(self, obj):
  return obj*20
```

Now i want those data to be passed in another SerializerMethod and do some other calculation.

something like this

```
cal2 = models.SerializerMethodField('__getcaltwo__')

def __getcaltwo__(self, obj):
  x = self.__getcal__(obj)
  return x*100
```

how can i achive this?

Comment: Have you tried your example? Looks like it might work, what was the result?

Comment: Can you also try `x = getattr(self.parent, '__getcal__')(obj)`